# Jenkins: Doing tests in RVM environment fails

Tags: jenkins, rvm

I have Jenkins on master machine (Windows) connected with node on Ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 12.04). They had been running together fine for some months, but a pair weeks ago I started to encounter problems with particular Rails project which tests should be run on Ubuntu machine. It started to require some rb-readline gem although it was already installed.

So I decided to move the /var/lib/jenkins/.rvm directory to other location to force RVM to be reinstalled. Then I removed RVM plugin from Jenkins and added it again. After all this I made it reinstall RVM, but now it can't perform any tasks in RVM environment. If I uncheck the "Run the build in a RVM-managed environment" option, the task could be completed without errors (if I remove specific build steps), but with this option set it cannot run even simple `echo test` command.

I returned the moved .rvm directory back to /var/lib/jenkins/, but this didn't help to get everything back.

Here is the error message (you will probably ask about `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project` directory - yes, it EXISTS):

```
Started by user Name Name
Building remotely on Web tests in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project
Checkout:my-project / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project - hudson.remoting.Channel@299bf5:Web tests
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision c595dcs8fthse8tw985t80wt5bst6volw8ebtt9g (origin/master)
Checkout:my-project / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my-project - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@48283482
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from https://TheUser:ThePassword@github.com/MyFirm/my-project.git
Commencing build of Revision c595dcs8fthse8tw985t80wt5bst6volw8ebtt9g (origin/master)
Checking out Revision c595dcs8fthse8tw985t80wt5bst6volw8ebtt9g (origin/master)
Capturing environment variables produced by 'rvm use 1.9.3'
$ bash -c export
$ bash -c "test ! -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[my-project] $ bash -c "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm_install_on_use_flag=1 && rvm use --create 1.9.3 && export > rvm.env"
FATAL: Native Exception: 'class java.io.IOException'; Message: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\my-project"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory; StackTrace: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\my-project"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:707)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:707)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:932)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:899)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: Native Exception: 'class java.io.IOException'; Message: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\my-project"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory; StackTrace: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\my-project"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:707)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:707)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:932)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:899)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:707)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "\var\lib\jenkins\workspace\my-project"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:707)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:932)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:899)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:287)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

There is another Jenkins instance installed directly on this Ubuntu machine and if I run the build of this project, It gives me an output as the corrupted Jenkins instance gave before: `Please 'gem install rb-readline' or recompile ruby --with-readline` but does not complain about Java. So, on the Ubuntu site everything seems to be not corrupted.